# Set python variable based on multiple conditions within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create some variables (to be used in other calculations) based on a dataframe conditional on a number of columns including date. But for the date condition I want to use a datetime variable I have already created.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
Date         Product  Sales
28/09/2022   apple    10.2
28/09/2022   orange   5.1
28/09/2022   pear     12.3 
27/09/2022   apple    4.1
27/09/2022   orange   3.9
27/09/2022   pear     15.0
```

My date variable (which is 28/09/2022)
`date = datetime.today()`

I'd like to create a variable called 'last_apple_sales' based on the dataframe where Date = my date variable and where Product = apple. So last_apple_sales = 10.2 in this case. And so on..

Had a go at using np.where with no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: if you got some "the truth value of an array is ambigious" or so error, try using np.logical_and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
mydate = datetime.now().date()
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date
last_apple_sales = df.loc[(df['Date'] == mydate) & (
    df['Product'] == 'apple'), 'Sales'].squeeze()
```

However, if your goal is to do that repeatedly, the best is to create a function:

```
def last_sales(df, mydate, product):
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date
    return df.loc[(df['Date'] == mydate) & (df['Product'] == product), 'Sales'].squeeze()

mydate = datetime.now().date()
last_sales(df, mydate, 'apple')
```

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime

text = """
Date         Product  Sales
28/09/2022   apple    10.2
28/09/2022   orange   5.1
28/09/2022   pear     12.3 
27/09/2022   apple    4.1
27/09/2022   orange   3.9
27/09/2022   pear     15.0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

def last_sales(df, mydate, product):
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date
    return df.loc[(df['Date'] == mydate) & (df['Product'] == product), 'Sales'].squeeze()

mydate = datetime.now().date()
last_sales(df, mydate, 'apple')
```

Comment: Thanks, still no joy. The code works but I am unable to see my new last_apple_sales variable. It appears as a Series type variable with a value of 'Series object of pandas.core.series module' ?

Comment: I have just added my complete code to my answer. Run that -- it should work fine and return `10.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter based on both conditions, select .max() and then .Sales

```
from datetime import datetime
df[(df.Date <= datetime(2022, 9, 28)) & (df.Product == 'apple')].max().Sales  # 10.2
```

Edit:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
# given date variable
date = datetime.today()
# create example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': {0: '28/09/2022', 1: '28/09/2022', 2: '28/09/2022', 3: '27/09/2022', 4: '27/09/2022', 5: '27/09/2022'},
     'Product': {0: 'apple', 1: 'orange', 2: 'pear', 3: 'apple', 4: 'orange', 5: 'pear'},
     'Sales': {0: 10.2, 1: 5.1, 2: 12.3, 3: 4.1, 4: 3.9, 5: 15.0}}
    )
# cast date strings to datetime objects
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')

# create last_apple_sales variable and assign...
last_apple_sales = df[(df.Date <= date) &  # filter dataframe to only include dates that are today or older (if you always use today to search, you can remove that line)
                      (df.Product == 'apple')  # filter dataframe to only include apple as a product
                      ].sort_values('Date', ascending=False).head(1).Sales  # sort values based on Date and select Sales for the latest date
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you response, but not sure I follow. What you've provided still requires code to select the date. The data will update everyday so I'd like a solution which will automatically select the variable based on my existing variable 'date'. I'd also appreciate the code which shows the solution to create my desired variable 'last_apple_sales'. Thanks

Comment: I've edited my example to include a little bit more comments. Please let me know if something is unclear :)